# how use pdfbox from groovy for compile ( unable to resolve class org.apache.pdfbox.util.Splitter )?

Tags: java, groovy, pdfbox

Im trying to using pdfbox and compile with groovy but I dont know

this is my code I use

groovyc main.groovy

but not works  please help me

```
this.class.classLoader.rootLoader.addURL(
   new URL("/usr/share/groovy/lib/pdfbox-2.0.11.jar"))



import org.apache.pdfbox.util.Splitter
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument

class Main {
    static void main(String[] args){

File pdfFile = new File(args[0])
PDDocument doc = new PDDocument().load(pdfFile)

Splitter splitter = new Splitter()
def count=0
splitter.split(doc).eachWithIndex{v,i->
  v.save(pdfFile.path[0..-5]+'_'+i.toString().padLeft(3,'0')+'.pdf')
  v.close()
}


}

}
```

Comment: What is the full error message you got? You also need fontbox and commons-log, see pdfbox website "dependencies".

Comment: Change your import to `org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.Splitter`, see https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.3/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/multipdf/Splitter.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.Splitter
```

to

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.Splitter
```

(see [javadoc](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.11/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/multipdf/Splitter.html))

Also make sure to include the needed [dependencies](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html), i.e. fontbox and commons-log and possibly more.